# Difference between boolean query and term query

Tags: elasticsearch

Difference between boolean query and term query.
As far as my understanding boolean query is combination of one or more query and term query is single query to match particular field.Am in right?

Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bool query literally combines multiple queries of any type together with clauses such as `must`, `must_not`, and `should`.

A term query specifies a single field and a single term to determine if the field matches. Note that term queries are specifically for **non-analyzed** fields.